# Erro em TransactionScope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando realizar um `TransactionScope` porém, sempre me dá um erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.NotSupportedException: A second operation
>   started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation
>   completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have
>   completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance
>   members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 150:            { Linha 151:                Cliente cliente =
>   await db.Clientes.SingleAsync(x => x.ClienteId == id); Linha 152:
>   Titulo titulo = await db.Titulos.Where(t => t.TituloId ==
>   cliente.Titulo.TituloId).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); Linha 153:
>   db.Titulos.Remove(titulo); Linha 154:                await
>   db.SaveChangesAsync();

Meu código no `controller` onde faço ele, está o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Excluir")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmarExclusao(Guid id)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        Cliente cliente = await db.Clientes.SingleAsync(x => x.ClienteId == id);
        Titulo titulo = await db.Titulos.Where(t => t.TituloId == cliente.Titulo.TituloId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        db.Titulos.Remove(titulo);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        db.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        scope.Complete();
        return RedirectToAction("Indice");
    }
}
```

Diferente do código acima, tentei utilizar o `ConfigureAwait();` nas linhas:

```
Cliente cliente = await db.Clientes.SingleAsync(x => x.ClienteId == id).ConfigureAwait(false);
Titulo titulo = await db.Titulos.Where(t => t.TituloId == cliente.Titulo.TituloId).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Mas não funcionou.

O que ocasiona este erro?

O que faço para corrigir?

Essa é a melhor forma para resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que ocasiona este erro?

Repare que aqui você usa como parâmetro uma classe agregada que ainda não foi carregada (`cliente.Titulo`):

```
Titulo titulo = await db.Titulos.Where(t => t.TituloId == cliente.Titulo.TituloId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Ou seja, quando você está executando esta parte, o Entity Framework está indo ao banco buscar `Titulo` por carga preguiçosa, justamente o que você está selecionando. Repare que neste ponto do código `cliente.Titulo` ainda não está carregado.

> O que faço para corrigir?

Apresse a carga na linha de cima e não use a linha de baixo para carregar:

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            var cliente = await db.Clientes
                                 .Include(c => c.Titulo)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClienteId == id);//.ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Este não precisa mais.
            // db.Titulos.Remove(titulo);
            // await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            db.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            scope.Complete();
            return RedirectToAction("Indice");
        }
```

> Essa é a melhor forma para resolver este problema?

Sim, pois você está pedindo ao Entity Framework observar `Cliente` e seu `Titulo` antes de apagá-los.